# Initiate message from bot in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to get the welcome message from bot first in dialogflow. I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas on how to do this.

I tried reading about events in dialogflow as Default welcome intent uses "Welcome" event. But not able to find any solution.

As I opened up my bot framework, it should pop up "Hi, I am a virtual assistant. How can I help you?"

Comment: On what integration are you testing this? For Messenger FACEBOOK_WELCOME event will be triggered when user taps "Get started" button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of which bot technology you are using, but if your front end is in html/js, you may call a function like this:

Define it something like:

function myFunction(){
    ''here you may pass a parameter to your bot to display a pre-defined message. I am not going in details here, as I am not sure about the framework you are using.'' 
  }

The onload (in body) will call myFunction(), everytime the page is refreshed.

P.s - I will update this answer once I get more details from your end. Since I am new here, please excuse in case of any issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Okay, you mean we can't do it in dialogflow platform itself. I have to do it in framework as I will use angularjs to integrate with dialogflow bot I am building.